# Are there any facebook APIs that make it possible to automate the installation of apps?

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm familiar with the Ruby koala API for Facebook, and I'm trying to batch install apps, maybe 100 at a time or so. Since this is going to be done twice a week, I'm looking for any APIs that might support this.

I've done this using watir-webdriver, but that's slow and I'd prefer not to.

Comment: _“and I'm trying to batch install apps”_ – and what exactly do you mean by “installing”?

Comment: I'll install a new set of 100 on Monday, and another 100 every Thursday. By install I mean add them to my account.

Comment: So you mean creating of new apps? There is no API for that, that has to be done manually. (And what would you need so many apps for anyway? This smells rather fishy already …)

Comment: No, I mean I'll be writing a script to add apps (go to app's page, click button to add to my profile, etc.). I'm doing security research.

Comment: This is not, and probably will not be possible ever. Sounds like something people could abuse pretty easily.